# What does xterm's Escape Sequence option do and how do I enable it?

Tags: configuration, xterm, escape-characters

xterm's <kbd>control</kbd>-*right-click* menu contains an option named *Escape sequence*. It is always disabled ("grayed out") in Ubuntu-14.04.

What is this option is used for? How do I enable it?

I am looking for this just in case enabling it enables displaying combined characters.

Answer (score 1):

As said by the xterm(1) man page concerning this menu item (see Section *VT Fonts*), "This allows you to set the font last specified by the Set Font escape sequence (see the document *Xterm Control Sequences*)". So, until you use such an escape sequence, this menu item is grayed out. Actually it remains grayed out, but this may be a bug. To try:

```
xterm -xrm '*allowFontOps: true'
printf "\e]50;#+1\a"
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned command, but it didn't work

Comment: @SHW The `printf "\e]50;#+1\a"` in the new xterm should increase the font size (it does for me), and should also ungray the *Escape Sequence* menu item, but as I've said, it remains grayed out. I've reported a bug in the Debian BTS: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=760208